# Unable to SSH to a VirtualBox RedHat

Tags: ssh, virtualbox

I am using a Mac and VirtualBox to start a RedHat virtual machine. The instance is started with two adapters (first being NAT, and second being host-only-adapter).

The problem is that I am unable to SSH from my Mac to the VirtualBox guest machine using its IP (I am able to ping the IP, though).

I checked the iptables and SSH was allowed (port 22), sshd daemon is also running. Anything I am missing?

Comment: What error are you getting? Tried to run `ssh -v ...` to get a clue?

Comment: This is what I get on my Mac:
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011

Comment: On my vm linux: OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

Comment: No, I didn't mean to check version of your SSH. I meant to run it in verbose mode `ssh -v user@host`.

Comment: This is what I get. `OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config

debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.101 [192.168.56.101] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.101 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.101 port 22: Connection refused`

Comment: Then your sshd is not listening on port 22 at 192.168.56.101. Is this the address of one of the interfaces you see from inside of your virtual system?

Comment: The only problem I can see is that eth1 has the same IP, and not eth0 (is that a problem?). I can ping to the same IP, by the way. Here is the result of ifconfig (sorry for the mess in the output!)


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:A7:D0:A3  
          inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:FA:14:48  
          inet addr:192.168.56.101  Bcast:192.168.56.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fefa:1448/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

Comment: And the /etc/sysconfig/iptables..


# Firewall configuration written by system-config-firewall
# Manual customization of this file is not recommended.
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I got the problem.. The thing was that I was using NAT as the network adapter one and hsot-only-adapter as the second one. I just needed to use the host-only-adapter as network adapter one and NAT as two, and the problem was solved.